# How to get TFS build to not measure coverage on 3rd party assemblies

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, code-coverage

How can I get my CI build to stop measuring coverage for the code (assemblies) that we didn't write in our projects in the solution?

We have code coverage turned on for our CI build of a solution in the TFS build definition.  When we run code coverage locally in Visual Studio we correctly get coverage reported for **just** the assemblies in the solution.  However, when we check-in and the CI build runs the code coverage reports coverage in other 3rd party assemblies that are referenced by the projects (both locally and on the CI build).

It is significantly skewing the code coverage % measured on the CI build since the 3rd party assemblies have many more blocks of code then our solution does.
The assemblies are not .net framework assemblies but other assemblies being pulled in from NuGet packages.

Comment: To be clear: I am aware of [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] and use it on our  unit test classes.  These are not the assemblies I'm concerned about.  They are correctly not contributing.  Concerned about 3rd party assemblies (which I cannot add the attribute to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use a run settings file you can exclude certain files from the code coverage.

the internals of the file will look like this

```
<ModulePaths>
   <Include>
     <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
    </Include>
    <Exclude>
       <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
       <ModulePath>.*test.*</ModulePath>
       <ModulePath>.*tests.*</ModulePath>
    </Exclude>
 </ModulePaths>
```

The above settings will exclude all test dll's from the coverage, you can just add the dll name fragment to the exclude node to ignore the dll from code coverage.

so Some3rdParty.dll would be excluded with

```
<ModulePath>.*Some3rdParty.*</ModulePath>
```

More details and the actual full contents of the runsettings file can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj635153.aspx

or a better explanation http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sudhakan/archive/2012/05/11/customizing-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-11.aspx

Comment: I have a template item for the runsettings file available at the VS Gallery,  see http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/704ebd18-7d60-4341-9224-532f73229c74 for VS 2013,  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/601bd207-5889-4935-b101-3ebe1f25aafa for VS 2012.

Comment: .runsettings did the trick.  As did deleting .pdbs from the output folder for 3rd party nuget packages that include them.  I still do not understand why some of the assemblies were being included that did not have .pdbs.  Documentation says only solution assemblies and assemblies with pdbs.  But runsettings works to get the build agent to behave the same as locally.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a lie ;:-) I've had build dlls included in coverage before, I had to remove build dll s from source and re add them from the build server in 2012 to stop them from being included!